# How to make EML file searchable?

Tags: document-library, search

I have a document library that will receive content via email each week (an email with around 4 attachments). When the library receives an email, it stores the email (as an EML file) and all of its attachments into a folder. So in the end, for each email that is sent to the library, one folder is created containing the contents of the email.

My question is: How can I set it up so that the contents of the EML file are searched when the user uses the site search bar? I would have thought that the email would be searchable by default but I have things that have been in the library for a few weeks now that are not appearing in the search results.

Comment: EML is a default file type indexed by the search service, so they should be getting indexed. A simple search in my environment for `FileType:EML` yields results and a search of `FileType:EML cheers` picks up body content. I'd look into your search settings in Central Administration.

Comment: Hmm that's kind of what I assumed. Thank you very much

Comment: @EricAlexander Everything looked alright in Central Administration. I did however notice that some of the files are still Pending. Their containing folder has been Approved, but the files within are still pending. I'm assuming a pending file is not included in the search result? If this is the case, feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it for future reference (or I can do it). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EML is a default file type indexed by the search service, so they should be getting indexed. A simple search in my environment for `FileType:EML` yields results and a search of `FileType:EML cheers` picks up salutations body content. I'd look into your search settings in Central Administration.

If the files are in a draft state or are pending approval, they may be omitted from the results unless you have permission to see draft items, per the standard search trimming functionality.